# Saving user details into a file in a login system?

Tags: python, authentication

I am producing a turn based game for a project and would like to create a user login system that saves the user's login username and password into a file in the game folder location. I would hope to then use the notepad file to check if there is already an account with that username when new users try to create a login.

In this code i attempted this but it is wrong?!

```
filename = 'UserInfo.txt' 
openfile = open(filename, "r")                                                          
UserData = openfile.readline()  
def displayMenu():
    print (UserData)
    status = input("Are you a registered user? y/n? ")  
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()

def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in UserData:
        print ("Login name already exist!")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        UserData[createLogin] = open('UserInfo','w')
        print("User created!")     
def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")
    if login in UserData and UserData[login] == passw: 
        print ("Login successful!")
    else:
        print ("User doesn't exist or wrong password")
displayMenu()
```

Comment: We have no idea if it's wrong, you need to tell us. You should take the time to read the rules [help], [mcve], and [faq].

Comment: I have said that it is wrong, i was just asking if anyone could fix the code so that it saves the user details into a notepad file?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't told us WHAT is wrong. Does it not save the names? Does it throw an error? Is the formatting wrong? Did your teacher not accept it for homework? We have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be putting the error message up but I think I have spotted what is wrong. In `newUser()` you are opening `'UserInfo'` not `'UserInfo.txt'` also open in a mode not w mode. So write `open('UserInfo.txt', 'a')`

You also need to read all the lines not just one line `openfile.readlines()`
Also remember to close the file after you open it in read mode or else it wont let you write to it:

```
openfile = open(filename, "r")   
UserData = openfile.readline()  
openfile.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @Sam no problem  ^^

Answer (score 1):

For the file you need to read all lines instead of line so use `openfile.readlines()` to check `if login in UserData`. And whenever you create a new user you need to append the new user into your file instead of overwriting the existing data in your file. So instead of using `open('UserInfo.txt', 'w')` you need to open with `a` mode like `open('UserInfo.txt', 'a')` which will append new data to the end of the file.